# How to force whole numbers to have one decimal place in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typesetting, information-graphics, script, chart-design

I make a lot of graphs using Illustrator for my company. Unfortunately, the graphing tool in Illustrator is very archaic. When adding number labels to graphs, Illustrator automatically removes .0 from numbers. I need all numbers to have the same sig figs. Is there a way to use GREP or any other kind of script to find whole numbers and add a .0 to the end? Or to force all numbers to include one decimal places?

Thank you in advance!
Steven

Comment: I assume you are aware that you can merely use the type tool to add a .0 to labels if needed.

Comment: I do suggest that you start making your own graphs with some scripting language. Its simple and you have much more control over the results than any other way.

Comment: @joojaa        Any advice on where to go to learn about creating scripted graphs?

Comment: @Scott.        Yes, I am aware of this. But, when making as many graphs as I do, it becomes tedious and creates an opportunity for error.

Comment: I dunno. I mean if you can ask a specific question about it i can answer but start simple.

Comment: @joojaa        For example, what scripting language would you use? You say it would be simple, but, my experience with scripting is pretty limited, but I would like to learn more.

Comment: Depends on what platform im working on. I might do it directly in postscript, benefit of this is i get a persistent file that can be printed or converted to pdf for free, and it places in adobe apps and updates on change. Or i might do it in javascript because the language is faster to type although the api in illustrator leaves stuff to be desired. Or i might to it in python over COM, since now i can tie it to excel. Or i might do it in Mathematica in case i need a lot of processing. Or i might do it in tixz, or python and tinkter. Or ...

Comment: @joojaa I realize it's very broad.. but I'd be all up for learning some javascript for custom charts as related to AI... the other languages are well above my head `:)`

Comment: @Scott ok ill prepare to do that. Will take some time.

Comment: @joojaa I'd never expect anything overly detailed.. just perhaps a few knowledgable bullet points on where to look to begin educating oneself and a general procedural outline. And.... only if the mood strikes you.. I realize that detailing things can not always be something someone *wants* to do. No harm if you simply don't want to.

Comment: @Scott still working on this (see deleted post below) I will need atleast another session before i can rlease it

Comment: Thanks a lot @joojaa I have been following :)  Very useful.. and greatly appreciated! You probably don't really care.. but max bounty! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can program your own graphs. This gives you total flexibility over the results. While this may seem daunting it is not. Most infographics are quite easy to codify, things like bar charts, line charts, radar charts, doughnut charts are all very easy to do.

All the simple charts build on the same code structure.

1. Get a array (or arraylike structure) of data
2. Loop over each item and draw a item.

   - draw any annotations etc...
3. Style items

OK lets start with a bar chart, for simplicity lets ignore how to obtain the data lets just make a dummy list and draw it

```
#target illustrator


data =[1.2, 3.0, 2.1, 0.42, 3.0, 1.1, 1.8];
doc = app.activeDocument;

// supporting vars
var mul = 24
var offsetX =100
var offsetY =-150


for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var val = data[i];
    var newPath = doc.pathItems.add();
    newPath.setEntirePath( [
      [i * mul + offsetX, 0 + offsetY],
      [i * mul + offsetX,  val *  mul  + offsetY]
    ]);
}
```

[image]

**Image 1**: Simple unstyled graph

Ok, this draws some lines. Why not boxes? Well its relatively easy for you to make a line into a rectangle by applying a style with a mitered offset, convert to shape, pattern brush or art brush. So I would prefer to leave the styling to styles as it means the same script can be reused easily. Likewise i would like to leave coloring of datasets to color group swtaches.

Let us modularize the thing a bit and add a named style and some colors to the lines. Still not entirely practivcal but lets remedy that later. I assume you have a style named "graph", with a mitered offset effect, and a color group named "graph".

```
#target illustrator

data =[1.2, 3.0, 2.1, 0.42, 3.0, 1.1, 1.8];
doc = app.activeDocument;

// supporting vars
var mul = 24
var offsetX =100
var offsetY =-150

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var val = data[i];
    var newPath = makeBarLine(i, val);
    setStyle(i, newPath);
}

function makeBarLine(i, val){
    var newPath = doc.pathItems.add();
    newPath.setEntirePath( [
        [i * mul + offsetX, 0 + offsetY],
        [i * mul + offsetX,  val *  mul  + offsetY]
    ]);
    return newPath
 }

function setStyle(i, pathitem){
    doc.graphicStyles.getByName("graph").applyTo( pathitem );
    pathitem.fillColor=doc.swatchGroups["graph"].getAllSwatches()[i].color;
}
```

[image]

**Image 2**: Same graph but with automated styling

Ok so far we have had a slightly unrealistic table in reality your data is most likely contained in some sort of list of lists.

```
#target illustrator
data =[["Apricot", 1.2],
            ["Banana", 3.0], 
            ["Clementine", 2.1],
            ["Dragon Fruit", 0.42], 
            ["Entawak", 3.0],
            ["Fig", 1.1], 
            ["Guava", 1.8]
            ];

var doc = app.activeDocument;

// supporting vars
var mul = 24
var offsetX =100
var offsetY =-150

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var val = data[i];
    var newPath = makeBarLine(i, val[1]);
    makeLabel(i,  val[0]);
    valueOnTop(i,  val[1]);
    setStyle(i, newPath);
}

function makeLabel(i, val){
         var ptext = doc.textFrames.add();
         ptext.contents = val;
         ptext.rotate(-70);
         ptext.left = i * mul + offsetX-10;
         ptext.top =  -10 + offsetY;
}

function valueOnTop(i, val){
         var ptext = doc.textFrames.add();
         ptext.contents = val.toFixed(1);
         ptext.left = i * mul + offsetX;    
         ptext.top = val *  mul  + offsetY+12 ;
         ptext.textRange.justification = Justification.CENTER;      
}


function makeBarLine(i, val){
    var newPath = doc.pathItems.add();
    newPath.setEntirePath( [
        [i * mul + offsetX, 0 + offsetY],
        [i * mul + offsetX,  val *  mul  + offsetY]
    ]);
    return newPath
 }

function setStyle(i, pathitem){
    doc.graphicStyles.getByName("graph").applyTo( pathitem );
    pathitem.fillColor=doc.swatchGroups["graph"].getAllSwatches()[i].color;
}
```

[image]

**Image 3**: Adding decoration is not much harder

So you see we can get incrementtaly better. THere is still one thing to fix. That is the system will fail if there are more bars than colors in the color set. And finally how to read a csv file for example. I will try to flesh this out tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for all the effort!

Answer (score 1):

The type controls in Illustrator are limited vs. InDesign.

You can build much more customized graphs in ID, with the full range of advanced controls over typography, with the downside that everything needs to be done by hand.

If the charts you're doing are always the same, but with different values, this can be partially automated or scripted.

There are also ingenious charting fonts like the FF Chartwell that could be handy. I use this alot, actually. See: [How to use EPS to build graphs in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/111277/how-to-use-eps-to-build-graphs-in-illustrator/111278#111278)

Not sure if this is what you wanted to read, but something to consider if you need to streamline that part.