# Wrapping lines around a (circle) path in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I have the following reference image:

[image]

What I am trying to do is recreate the sound wave like design wrapped around a circle path like in the image above. However, the distort effect doesn't produce a perfect circle wrap and doesn't really allow for 'randomization' of the waves.

I have found the following [topic](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/80938/how-to-create-a-line-graph-around-a-circle)

And it works but it really lacks control over maintaining that circle look. Is there an alternative way to achieve this effect?

Comment: i dont see  how it lacks control since it can do the outer  line easily. the bars wouldnt be hard to do either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using creating a brush pattern and then using the ellipse tool to make a circle!

Draw out a sound wave pattern using the *Pen Tool* or *Brush Tool*, then from the *Window* dropdown menu, select the **Brush** window. Press **v** *(Selection Tool)*, and then drag the pattern to the brush menu. When prompted for the type of brush, select **Pattern Brush**, and then the following options:

[image: Pattern Brush Options]

- Scale: Fixed
- Spacing: 0%
- Fit: Stretch to fit

With the circle selected, if you select your new brush stroke, it should make something like this which you can color and adjust other settings as you like.

[image: Final Product]

Obviously, the more intricate the original pattern is, the better the final product will be.